# AJAX Scroll - contents are "html-files" = possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Is ist possible to use html-files for new contents instead of text or pictures?
I found this script i want to use: http://www.inserthtml.com/2013/01/scroll-pagination/

I have already changed the ajax.php - now i get the link from the html-file from mysql-database `(for example: news_1.html).`

but now i want to show instead of the TEXT `news_1.html` the content from the html-file.

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes. Of course it is. Modifying HTML is the main thing that JS is used for.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to add this in the ajax.php : $news = file_get_contents($content); --> now I see the html-files as content in the div BUT between the contents are "spare lines" and i don't know why? (greets from Austria -> sry about my englisch ;)